# Auto refresh data from json to angular

Tags: angularjs, json

Good day, I want to create `auto refresh`, so when the data(s) updated the field will change too. So, i'm trying to use `$interval`. Please check my script

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('listsupport', function($scope,$http,$interval) {
        var count = 0;
        $http.get("<?=base_url();?>newchat/listsupport").then(function (response) {
            $scope.names = response.data;
            $interval( function(){listsupport();}, 10000);
        }); 

    });
</script>
```

with my script above, i get an error `listsupport is not defined`. How can i fix it ? thank's in advance.

Comment: where did you defined function `listsupport `?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
app.controller('listsupport', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
this.interval = $interval(function() {

    $http.get("<?=base_url();?>newchat/listsupport").then(function(response) {
        $scope.names = response.data;

    });
}, 10000);
});
```